# UICollectionViewCell and UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I encountered a weird behavior of UIScrollView when inside a UICollectionViewCell. In my project I have a collectionView and each cell has a UIScrollView that contains 1 or more images. Here's some sample code for purpose of this question:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

     CustomCollectionCell * cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 150)];
     imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];        
     [cell.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

     return cell;
}
```

Of course in my project it's not the same image but different ones that are fed from a database.

The first collection cell is added with no problem. When I add the second cell, the scrollView seems to duplicate itself and place another instance of itself on top. I know it sounds weird, but you can see how it looks in the image below:

[image]

Notice how the image in the scrollView on the left has darkened, I assume it's because the scrollView get duplicated.

So, I'm guessing that the cell is reused in a wrong way or something.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new `UIImageView` is being added to the reused cell each time `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is invoked.  To solve this, in the custom `UICollectionViewCell`, implement the `prepareForReuse` method.  In that method, remove the image view.

To accomplish this, you could set a tag on the image view.  E.g.,:

```
 (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

     CustomCollectionCell * cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 150)];
     imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];        
     [cell.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

     // The following line of code is new
     cell.contentView.tag = 100;

     return cell;
}
```

And to remove the image view from the cell, add/update the `prepareForReuse` method in the custom cell:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
    UIView *myImageView = [self.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    [myImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Alright, that fixed part of the issue, it doesn't duplicate, however now I notice another weird issue. If I change the content offset by swiping in one cell' scrollViews, the content offset gets passed to the next cell, and the previous one may get the new one's content offset (i.e. x=0, y=0).

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain because I don't really understand the reason for this behavior, sorry :)

Comment: As I understand, the whole collectionView is updated each time a new cell is added. Which causes very strange results when the cell has a scrollView added. I was thinking that only the new cell is modified, but I see that all the cells are reused

Comment: @SergeyCatraniuc - suggest you accept the above answer ;-), then create a new question showing the code for the `UIScrollView`

Comment: My question wasn't answered completely, however I think I'm going to ditch the UIScrollView and find a workaround using a UIImageView instead. Thanks for your help